# Differential equation $4x^3y+x^4y'=\sin^3x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not even sure if I set this up right, I just learned this concept and I'm still a little shaky on it.

I divided everything by x^4 to put it into proper form: $y'+(4/x)y = \sin^3x/x$ What I got was $I(x)= x^4$ and then $yx^4=\int x\sin^3x.$ I don't think I set it up correctly. I'd appreciate some help on how to set the equation up.

Comment: You're missing a $y$ in the first term? (And in your text, if you divide $\sin^3x$ by $x^4$ you don't get $(\sin^3 x)/x$ :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: What is the derivative of $x^4y(x)$?

Comment: So my left side was correct? Product rule of x^4y so taking the integral of that would be $x^4y$ and then just integrate the right side $xsin^3(x)$?

Comment: No, you just integrate $\sin^3 x$ (with a constant of integration), and at the end you divide by $x^4$, right?

Comment: At first I divided all terms with $x^3$ to get proper form and then I multiplied all by I(x) = $x^4$, so it is $xsin^3(x)$, correct? Unless I did something incorrect to the right side.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I'm getting all mixed up, thanks for the tip.